# Measuring 60 Hz AC from a piece of wire

Tags: voltage-measurement

I am trying to measure the presence 60 Hz AC signals using various shapes of wire antennas.
I will be sending the voltage present on these antennas into a high impedance op amp stage. But before I do this, I would like to know if I can get away with measuring the AC voltage with a O-scope probe which does not use the ground clip. I have taken several different measurements in locations where there was a strong E field and a weak E field.

Additional information added 5/27/15:

The goal is to determine whether 60 Hz is present as well as to determine whether the voltage measured at a given position has increased if the antenna is move closer to the source. I will be sending this voltage to active components downstream. I was just want to know if connecting my O-scope probe to various length antennas without using the ground clip invalidates the reading.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Remove ground antenna, touch tip, watch 60Hz waveform, no additional wires needed (unless you are interested in a more accurate resemblence of the waveform). I am not sure though why you ask about it here when you could just quickly test it

Comment: I think it would be a good idea for you to explain a lot more about what you are trying to do and why you want to do it. If you are looking at a wire and you want to know if it is "hot" there are non-contact voltage probes used by electricians. If you are looking at a single wire, and you want to know if there is current flowing in it, you can put a clamp meter around it (has to be a single wire). There may be a good solution for what you are trying to do using off the shelf items.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right, but I interpret it as this:

"If I measure a 60Hz signal with a wire end or open probe connected to my Oscilloscope, does that mean anything in a noise sense?"

The short answer, not really.

The long answer includes "it might".

You can measure the presence of the 60Hz and use that to know... that the building you're in has a 60Hz outlet somewhere. It's probably powering at least your oscilloscope.

The amplitude on your scope does have a significance to the strength of the electro-magnetic field in which your wire or probe lies, but orientation, unshielded length (including the effective length any tuning components inside your probe might add) will have a large influence in how much it picks up.

As does the design of whatever you are measuring the noise for. In your case the antennas, the length and orientation, as well as any tuning components such as inductances and capacitances to make them resonate - or get them to (partial) wavelength -, will have a great effect on the voltage at the amplifier. An antenna can go through some simple steps to swoop up to 10's of volts, or can drive only microvolts, depending on the level of tuning to the intended signal.

((60Hz is a very long wave though, so tuning will take "large" components))

So, in a shorter form: If you know the exact specifics of the thing you are measuring as compared to the eventual system, yes you could potentially get an impression, but just hooking up a scope to a wire and saying "Oh, look, an antenna like this will give a 20mV signal on my eventual set-up" is (almost) never going to work that easily. Things like grounded bulk alone might make differences (your scope has a big metal case connected to power ground and this *might* have an effect).